# error message when no default value in selectizeInput specified in r shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Here is a simple app to illustrate my problem. When I use selectizeInput without specify the default value,  the mainpanel simply shows a error message. What I need is a empty plot if nothing selected. How do I modify my code?

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)


ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput('var', 'choose variable', 
                           choices = names(mtcars),
                           options = list(
                               placeholder = 'Please select an option below',
                               onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))
                           )

        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput('hist')
        )
    )

)


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$hist <- renderPlot ({
        hist (eval(parse(text=(paste0('mtcars$', input$var)))))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When nothing is selected in the `selectizeInput`, the value of the input is `""`, so you call `eval(parse())` on the string `mtcars$` which is bad syntax. You should not use `eval(parse())`, but validate the input value before trying to plot the histogram, e.g. in your server :

```
output$hist <- renderPlot ({
  validate(need(input$var, 'Choose a variable!'))
  hist(x = mtcars[[input$var]])
})
```

If you dont want to display a message, you can just do `req(input$var)` before calling `hist`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!   a followup question:  why you need double square brackets to access the variable?

Comment: You're welcome, please accept my answer if it solve your problem. For the data.frame subsetting it's because data.frames are named list, so you can access element with `$` or `[[` like with list. You could do `mtcars[, iput$var]` as well. Look at this cheatsheet, it's well explained : http://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/source/pdfs/base-r.pdf